# Alternative to string.split

Tags: javascript, jquery

Making a GET request, I recieve a string that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="http://myUrl.com">you said:This is a test --&gt;SHA1:7d9d2886509cfd1dfd3c693fff43b82561ec00a18621ce784d65b912e2013df6</string>
```

But I am only interested in the part that says: This is a test. How I would achieve this is by using the string.split (and taking substring etc) function of JS/JQuery. But I am thinking that maybe there is an smarter way of doing this that I don't know of yet? Would you experienced programmers have the same approach as me, with the string.split?

Comment: experienced programmers will setup the file of the get request so only the  substring is returned

Comment: @madalinivascu Jesus you guys so hostile. I don't have access to that file, I only have a url I can call, and that returns what you see

Comment: @user1960836 Take no notice of madalin, some people don't look at the bigger picture. It's perfectly plausible that the service you call you have no control over, so "experienced programmers" will work with what they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should really just return the string back that you need, not the XML. If this is beyond your control however, then use the following:

Parse the XML in jquery (using [`$.parseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)), then query it:

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="http://myUrl.com">you said:This is a test --&gt;SHA1:7d9d2886509cfd1dfd3c693fff43b82561ec00a18621ce784d65b912e2013df6</string>';

var parsed = $($.parseXML(xml));

var test = parsed.find("string");

alert(test.text());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o87e7bo6/)

Comment: author wanted to use `string.split()` to get rid of "you said" ;) you should add that

Comment: @BenWin He also said *"But I am thinking that maybe there is an smarter way of doing this that I don't know of yet? "*. I gave him the smarter way :)

Comment: True! But you parse back _you said:This is a test_. I just wanted to point out to, however this is accomplished, you get rid of _you said:_ :D but i just maybe misread the question

Comment: Thanks @mattytommo, that indeed is a smarter way I was looking for

Comment: @user1960836 No problems glad I could help, don't let the "unfriendly people" in the community put you off :)